# An email service that offers imap access as well as sending?

Tags: ruby, email, sendgrid, mailgun, postmark

I have been hunting for some time now for a service that both allows sending of messages and receiving of messages in a conveniently wrapped solution such as MailGun, Postmark, SendGrid and others.  So far I have not been any "developer friendly" solution that facilitates both an smtp service + an imap service for receipt and account management for large quantities (ie, Google Apps is not acceptable).

Am I overlooking a robust already existent solution or do I need to roll my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MailGun, Postmark, SendGrid You do not need them. can speak directly with a server.
I post [part one](https://gist.github.com/fishbullet/8586900) and [part two](https://gist.github.com/fishbullet/8586912) for example what i use. 
Have fun!